# PHP Creating a new type of array from an array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array of data:

```
$data = array(
 0 => array(
   'firstname' => 'John',
   'lastname' => 'Doe'
 ),
 1 => array(
   'firstname' => 'Foo',
   'lastname' => 'Bar'
 )
)
```

And Id like to manipulate it to end up with this array:

```
$finalData = array(
 'firstname' => array('John','Foo'),
 'lastname' => array('Doe','Bar')
)
```

How do I accomplish this using PHP? Id love to learn about the PHP array methods if one can be used in this scenario.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is too specialized for functions like `array_map` without shooting yourself in the foot. But you can easily do it with a `foreach` loop:

```
$finalData = array();
foreach ($data as $person) {
    $finalData['firstname'][] = $person['firstname'];
    $finalData['lastname'][] = $person['lastname'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to loop through $data  to gather first names and last names separately. Unfortunately there is no standard php function that performs "array pluck".

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think that something like that exist, but I think You should read [docs on array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php)

If You don't find anything, make something your own (probably with with array_map), and please answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

This gives what you want;

```
$new_data = array();
foreach ($data as $d) {
    $keys = array_keys($d);
    foreach ($keys as $k) {
        $new_data[$k][] = $d[$k];
    }
}
print_r($new_data);
```

Result;

```
Array
(
    [firstname] => Array
        (
            [0] => John
            [1] => Foo
        )

    [lastname] => Array
        (
            [0] => Doe
            [1] => Bar
        )

)
```